# Make Image Clickable on Slide Show

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using this code for slide show. I can't seem to get the image clickable without losing the name in the 'name' div.

What I'm after is to be able to click on a picture on the slide show and be able to go to the details page. Whenever I get the image clickable, the name does not display in the 'name' div; and if I remove the link, then the name will display.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Pager Demo with Prev/Next Controls</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../jq.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cycle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#main { margin: 20px }
#nav { margin: 10px; position: relative }
#nav li { float: left; list-style: none}
#nav a { margin: 5px; padding: 3px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none }
#nav li.activeSlide a { background: #faa; color: black }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#slideshow').cycle({
          prev:    '.prev', // Setup prev links
          next:    '.next', // Setup next links
          pager:   '.nav',       // Setup pager navs          
          before: function () {         
          $("#name").text(this.alt);     }
     }); 
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#left, #slideshow, #right { float: left; width: 200px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- left nav bar -->
<div id="left">
    <a href="#"><span class="prev">Prev</span></a> 
    <a href="#"><span class="next">Next</span></a>

    <ul class="nav"></ul>
</div>

<!-- slideshow -->
<div id="slideshow">


 <?php
                 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect");
                 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

                 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people") or die(mysql_error());
                 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
    <!--HERE ON THIS LINE---- > echo "<a href=\"show.php?id=".$info['id']."\"><img src=\"http://localhost:8080/about/images/".$info['photo'] . "\" alt=\"".$info['name'] ."\"/>"; 
  }
?>

</div>

 <div id="name">

 </div>
 <!-- right nav bar -->
 <div id="right">
     <a href="#"><span class="prev">Prev</span></a> 
     <a href="#"><span class="next">Next</span></a>
     <ul class="nav"></ul>
 </div>


 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem comes from your *before* parameter in the cycle definition

```
function () { $("#name").text(this.alt); }
```

It should be something like

```
function () { $("#name").text($(this).children("img").attr("alt")); }
```

I can't test it right now, though.

Comment: That was simply AWESOME! Thanks for that - it worked like magic :)

Answer (score 0):

Never used `cycle` plugin personally, but I think you are not attaching click callback to the image at all. Instead, you  attaching it on `before`, which makes `name` be displayed in your `div` when images start swapping. See [`cycle` plugin reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) for details

To display image name on click use the following code:

```
$('.clickable_image').click(function(){
    $('#name').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Don't forget to add class `clickable_image` to your images.

Also, if you plan add images dynamically, [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this affects the jQuery code or not because I can't test it right now, but you don't have a closing A tag.

Should look like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"show.php?id=".$info['id']."\"><img src=\"http://localhost:8080/about/images/".$info['photo'] . "\" alt=\"".$info['name'] ."\"/></a>";
```

Comment: I added the closing A tag and still does not make any difference. Will keep trying. Thanks again